# MySQL Version for right syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting this error on the SQL schema. The error message i am getting is

> "
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CREATE TRIGGER updtrigger_r4_balance AFTER  UPDATE    ON
>   resellers4 FOR EACH R' at line 2"

What syntax is going wrong? I am attaching 2 SQL schema. Both having same problem.

```
delimiter // DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS updtrigger_r4_balance;
CREATE TRIGGER updtrigger_r4_balance AFTER 
UPDATE
   ON resellers4 FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN
      IF NEW.callsLimit <= 0 
   THEN
      UPDATE
         resellers4_child r4c 
         INNER JOIN
            resellers3 r3 
            ON (r4c.reseller3_id = r3.id) 
      SET
         r4c.reseller3_callsLimit = r4c.reseller3_callsLimit + r3.callsLimit, r3.callsLimit = 0 
      WHERE
         r4c.reseller4_id = new.id;
   END
   IF;
END
// delimiter ;
```

Another one is:

```
delimiter //
DROP TRIGGER
IF EXISTS updtrigger_r4_balance_add;

CREATE TRIGGER updtrigger_r4_balance_add BEFORE UPDATE ON resellers4 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF OLD.callsLimit <= 0 THEN

    UPDATE resellers3 r3
    INNER JOIN resellers4_child r4c ON (r4c.reseller3_id=r3.id) 
    SET
                r3.callsLimit = r3.callsLimit+r4c.reseller3_callsLimit,
                r4c.reseller3_callsLimit = 0

    WHERE r4c.reseller4_id=new.id;

END IF;

END
//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Why do you tag MS SQL Server and Sqlite, but not MySQL?

Comment: You changed your delimiter to `//`. So you have to end your `drop ...`-statement with `//`, not with `;`. Also your `"` indicates that you are executing your code not directly in mysql, but from some other programming language. Not every command that can execute a single query can execute more than one query (drop and create) or a changed delimiter, so maybe check the correct syntax for a multiquery/delimiter in whatever language you run that.

Comment: @Solarflare: Can you post me the code with right syntax?

Answer (score 3):

After you change the delimiter you have to use it instead of `;`

```
delimiter //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS updtrigger_r4_balance_add; <--- use // instead
```

Answer (score 0):

Also after delimiter changes try to replace word new in statement

```
r4c.reseller4_id = new.id;
```

with uppercase one. Because OLD and NEW are MySQL extensions to triggers, so they aren't case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL uses `;` to separate the queries. Multiple queries can be sent to the server in a single request; the server use the current delimiter (default `;`) to split the received text into queries.

There are complex SQL constructs (triggers, stored procedures etc) that may include one or more queries or a [`BEGIN..END`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/begin-end.html) compound statement in their definition.

Because such constructs usually contains two or more queries, separated by the usual delimiter (`;`), MySQL needs a way to know where the enclosing compound construct ends.

The `DELIMITER` statement is used to replace the default delimiter (`;`) with a different one when a compound statement is defined. This allows the standard delimiter (`;`) to be used inside the body of the compound statement.

It works this way:

1. The `DELIMITER` statement is used to change the current delimiter; various values are used as delimiter instead. `//` is suggested in the documentation but other values can be used too. The only rule is to use a character (or a sequence of characters) that does not appear in the compound statement that is to be defined after it.
2. From now on, all the subsequent queries must end with the new delimiter (and not with `;`).
3. Declare the complex construct (be it a trigger, stored procedure at event). If it contains more than one statements they have to be separated by `;`.
4. End the complex construct with the delimiter declared on step 1.
5. Use `DELIMITER ;` to reset the delimiter. If another statement follows then you have to terminate the `DELIMITER` statement with the delimiter you set on step 1 (because it is the current delimiter; the new one becomes effective after this statement is parsed and executed).

The solution of your problem is simple: either you use the delimiter you set (`//`) to separate the `DROP TRIGGER` and the `CREATE TRIGGER` statements:

```
delimiter //

DROP TRIGGER
IF EXISTS updtrigger_r4_balance_add //

CREATE TRIGGER updtrigger_r4_balance_add BEFORE UPDATE ON resellers4 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    ...
END
//
delimiter ;
```

Or you move the `DROP TRIGGER` statement before the `DELIMITER` statement and leave it as it is (terminated with `;`):

```
DROP TRIGGER
IF EXISTS updtrigger_r4_balance_add;

delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER updtrigger_r4_balance_add BEFORE UPDATE ON resellers4 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    ...
END
//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks alot dude. (y)